# Can the $\min$ function take countably infinitely many arguments?

Tags: order-theory

Can the $\min$ function take countably infinitely many arguments?

That is, does it make sense to have $\min(a_1, a_2, ...)$?

Comment: It *can* make sense, but it doesn't always make sense.  Better to use $\inf$ in such a scenario.

Comment: It depends on the set composition, by example $\min(\Bbb N_{\ge 1})=1$. But in many other cases it doesnt exist.

Comment: $\min(a, a, a, \cdots)$ makes sense...

Comment: The `inf` of a finite set is precicely it's `min`; with this in mind, consider compact sets ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it could, what would be $\min(0,1,-1,2,-2,\ldots)$? In fact, what would be $\min(1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots)$?

For infinite sets we no longer guaranteed to have a minimum. But we do have an *infimum*, at least as far as bounded subsets of the real numbers are involved. So we can talk about $\inf(1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots)=0$.

Note, by the way, that the $\inf$ function actually takes a *set*, not just a countable family of arguments. We can talk about $\inf(\{x\mid x^3>2\})=\sqrt[3]2$, for example. But as luck would have it, we can show that every set can be reduced to a countable sequence which converges to its infimum.

Comment: Right, this makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An infinite min only makes sense if you  are dealing with subsets of a well ordered set.  Well ordered sets have the property that any subset has a unique minimum element.

For example $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered as is any ordinal.  Well ordered sets are useful because they allow you to do induction on them.